# GreaseMonkey, change some js functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I use Greasemonkey for some changes in pages.

There's a web page that has `SomeFunction()` placed in a javascript file.
I ignored the javascript file with some add-ons.
Now `SomeFunction()` should be overwritten.

But when I define `SomeFunction()` in GM script, I get "`SomeFunction()` is not defined" which has not been resolved by `run-at document-start` in GM script neither by adding `SomeFunction()` in a file and writing that on the page with `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);`.

How can I define a custom `Somefunction()`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider reading [`exportFunction`](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/04/10/changes-to-unsafewindow-for-the-add-on-sdk/#user-content-exportfunction) and all the others stuff about `unsafeWindow`.

Basically:

```
exportFunction(SomeFunction, unsafeWindow, {defineAs: "SomeFunction"});
```